# Can you name this Sci-Fi film set around receiving a signal from space and building a structure?

Tags: identify-this-movie, science-fiction

Trying to remember the name of a film. This one has been bugging me for ages!

Published in the 00's, the film's plot goes something like this:

The Nazi's broadcast a video into space to celebrate their achievements with technology.
Years later, satellites listening to space pick up the exact same video being sent back to earth.  But this time, it has been highly amplified and also contains noise/distortion.
They then find out the noise has patterns and is essentially code embedded in the video.

Long story short, they realise the code is blueprints to build a huge structure which they 'think' might be a teleporter or something. The world invests money into building the space port thing.  On the day of launch, it gets bombed.
People then learn that a second port was built by private investors and they use that instead.
A girl enters the device and it seamed to malfunction... But she believes she was transported somewhere.

I really cant remember the name, actors or anything but I'd like to watch it again!!!
All help appreciated!!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's [Contact](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118884), released in 1997, starring Jodie Foster.  The 'Nazi video' is actually a TV broadcast of the 1936 Olympic opening ceremony. The signal which is received on Earth includes this broadcast, enabling the Earth scientists to calculate how far away the source of the response is.

Comment: James Woods, Jodie Foster and Matthew McConaughey were all in it.  Great movie; whenever I feel overwhelmed I just watch the opening 2 minutes of that movie to realize how insignificant I really am.  :o)  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vGyq7d62oPQ

Comment: I actually ruled out contact because it was 97. I remember seeing it in the cinema but didn't realise I was so young at the time! Will watch it tonight :-)